# EXT js edit row

Tags: extjs

i have a little problem, in this time i have decided to do the consult in sql each time i update a row with Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing, i paste the part of my code where i have my problem.

```
   var gridTablaConsulta = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
    title:'Consulta Tabla lotes',
    store: storeTabla,
    columns: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
        {text: "NRBE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NRBE'},
        {text: "APLIC", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'APLIC'},
        {text: "FORM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FORM'},
        {text: "VERFOR", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'VERFOR'},
        {text: "FECLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECLOT'},
        {text: "HORLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORLOT'},
        {text: "TIPPAPLO", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPPAPLO'},
        {text: "TAMPAP", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TAMPAP'},
        {text: "FECINIIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIIM'},
        {text: "FECINIOB", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIOB'},
        {text: "ESTLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'ESTLOT'},
        {text: "TOTPAGGE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGGE'},
        {text: "TOTPAGIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGIM'},
        {text: "DESLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DESLOT'},
        {text: "TIPDIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPDIF', editor: {xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false}},
        {text: "DIADIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DIADIF', editor: {xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false} },
        {text: "FECALT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECALT'},
        {text: "FECMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECMOD'},
        {text: "TERMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TERMOD'},
        {text: "HORMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORMOD'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ],

    listeners: {
        edit: function(e){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                method: 'POST',

                params: {
                    Funcionalidad: 'Modificar',
                    DPNrbe: Ext.getCmp('DPNrbe').getValue(),
                    DPAplic: Ext.getCmp('DPAplic').getValue(),
                    DPForm:Ext.getCmp('DPForm').getValue(), 
                    DPVersFor: Ext.getCmp('DPVerFor').getValue(),
                    DPFecLot: Ext.getCmp('DPFecLot').getValue(),
                    DPHorLot: Ext.getCmp('DPHorLot').getValue(),
                    DPTippApl: Ext.getCmp('DPTippApl').getValue(),
                    DPTamPap: Ext.getCmp('DPTamPap').getValue(),
                    DPFecinIm: Ext.getCmp('DPFecinIm').getValue(),
                    DPFeciNio: Ext.getCmp('DPFeciNio').getValue(),
                    DPEstLot: Ext.getCmp('DPEstLot').getValue(),
                    DPTotPagge: Ext.getCmp('DPTotPagge').getValue(),
                    DPTotPagim: Ext.getCmp('DPTotPagim').getValue(),
                    DPDesLot: Ext.getCmp('DPDesLot').getValue(),
                    DPTipDif: Ext.getCmp('DPTipDif').getValue(),
                    DPDiaDif: Ext.getCmp('DPDiaDif').getValue(),
                    Entorno:  Ext.getCmp('Entorno').getValue()
                 },
                success: function(){

                      var text = response.responseText;
                        // process server response here
                      respuestaModificacion(text);

                    },
                    failure:  function (){
                    alert("Desde failure");
                    },
                    exception: function (){
                   alert("Desde exception");
                 }
            });
        }
    }


});
```

I have my problem in the part where i must save the changes that i have done in the rox when i push update. I think that this  DPNrbe: Ext.getCmp('DPNrbe').getValue(), is incorrect, but what i must put here to do correct the sql consult.

I need to save all the values of the row even the not changes camps, because i must do next a consult in a sql ( a update with the changes values).

Thanks for all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you don't have editor fields for each of your columns, so your can't access the cell value this way. But, you see in the doc of the [`edit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-edit) event, that it passes a `context` argument to the listener, in which you can access the store record being edited.

For example:

```
        edit: function(e, context){

            // see edit event doc
            var record = context.record;

            // get the row's data (will be updated from the last edit)
            var recordData = record.getData();

            console.log(recordData); // see what's in there

            // add custom param
            recordData.Functionalidad = 'Modificar';

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                method: 'POST',

                // merge row data with other params
                params: recordData,

                // callbacks code omitted
                success: function() { /* ... */ },
                failure:  function() { /* ... */ },
                exception: function () { /* ... */ }
            });
        }
```

Also, just an advice, maybe you should consider using [`jsonData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) instead of `params` in your request, because JSON may save you some annoying string casts on the server-side.

Comment: I dont understand at all, is enough with the code that you have pasted? On the other hand I used json in the servlet.

Comment: Yes it should be enough. I have edited my example code to make it simpler and more explicit. Maybe you should read the [grid panel guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/grid), that also explains stores and models.

Comment: Thanks i will try, with that code i obtein all camps? even the no changes?

Comment: It dosent work, i pulse the update button but it dosent do the consult.

Comment: Where does it fail? Does the execution reach the listener? Can you see the request fired in the developer tools (e.g. Firebug)? Does the request seems to contains the right data?

Comment: Yes, enter in the listener but appears that console si not defined.

Comment: Oh. That line was just to show you that we got all the record's field data in a simple object. You can remove it (place a debugger instead if you want to inspect the data object).

Comment: yes i have erased that part, i will prove now the debuger. I quit the console, i run the debugger and appears bad formed when i lunch the servlet

Comment: i have found the problem here is: recordData.Functionalidad = 'Modificar' is must be recordData.Funcionalidad = 'modificar'

Comment: Nice. Do not hesitate to mark the answer as accepted or useful if it has helped you with your problem ;)

Comment: but now i find a new problem org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() para servlet servlets.ServletTablaLotes lanzó excepción
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GestorBBDD.GestorBBDDOracle.modificarTabla5(GestorBBDDOracle.java:551)

Comment: SO is oriented on the question/answer format, extended discussions about a whole case are discouraged. Feel free to ask other questions about your other issues. Trying to isolate the problem at a maximum will bring you answers of top quality!

Comment: Ok, but the problem is now that the data dont arrive to the servlet... it dont have any value

Comment: I do a alert(recordata) and i only see [object,object]

Comment: May be a good sign... Use `alert(JSON.stringify([{a:1}], 0, 2))` to see the objects content.

Comment: ok lets go to see, it said that argument of replace not valide

Comment: is it neccesary any library to use stringfy?? i use json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Nope, standard browser stuff.

Comment: i will try to do alert(JSON.stringify(recordData)) i think that i dont need the oter values, perfect i see all data values... but not the funcionalidad=modificar.. for that i have problem in my server...

Comment: perfect i see all data values even the funcionalidad ( i put the alert before add funcionalidad ^^)...ok.. then i suposse i must work in my servlet

Comment: now my question is, is enought this (request.getParameter("Funcionalidad")) to get for example the funcionalidad??

Comment: Perfect y find my problem i supose, that when i evaluate the response i evaluated even the funcionalidad...

Comment: Thnaks for all, now all is perfect, the error was that i search for DPNrbe in my sevrlet now i have change to NRBE and all is perfect.. thanks very much... i am in eternal gratitude with you